# Angular ADFS FederationMetadata.xml, clientId

Tags: c#, angular, adfs, adal

I am trying to resolve a problem with Sign-In to ADFS on premise from Angular. We have received a FederationMetadata.xml. However, all examples for angular adal require a clientId. Is that something I can get from there?
I am able to get the login url, when I put the AddWsFederation to my C# Controller and call  HttpContext.ChallengeAsync. However I would like to have more clients on one server, so I would prefer something more flexible. MS examples have only one clientId in the web.config and setup them at the start.
Thank you very much for any piece of advice.

Answer (score 0):

The metadata file is for a SAML or WS-Federation connection.

Client_id implies an OpenID Connect connection.

Typically, Angular connections would use OpenID Connect e.g. [sample here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/single-page-application-with-ad-fs).

What version of ADFS? If 2019, rather use the MSAL rather than the ADAL sample.

That sample shows the ADFS configuration.

They then need to send you the client_id, redirect_url etc.

This information is not contained in the metadata.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will ask for the ADFS version and for the client_id. (I was afraid to ask for that in case it is contained in the xml file :) )